# How do you solve these kinds of system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations

Recently, I came across this system of equations,

\begin{align}
\begin{cases} \dfrac{2x}{p(p+4)}=\dfrac{2x}{q(q-4)}=3 & (1) \\ \dfrac{x}{p+q} = 4 & (2) \end{cases}
\end{align}

or

\begin{align}
\begin{cases} \dfrac{2x}{p(p+4)}=\dfrac{2x}{q(q-4)}=3 & (1) \\ \dfrac{y}{p+4} = \dfrac{x-y}{q-4} = 4 & (2) \end{cases}
\end{align}

It would be a great help if someone can help me solve these.

Thanks!

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ prime numbers? Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @DietrichBurde No, p and q are not prime numbers.

Comment: Are p and q integers or real numbers ?

Comment: @JeanMarie x, y, p and q, all of them are variables. In the context of the question, all of them would be positive integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the first set of fractions:
\begin{align}
\frac{2 \, x}{p (p+4)} &= \frac{2 \, x}{q (q-4)} = 3 \\
\frac{x}{p+q} &= 4
\end{align}
it would seem that the relations lead to an equation for $p$ and $q$. This follows from solving for $x$ in the second equation, $x = 4 \, (p+q)$, and using it in the first which gives
$$ \frac{8 \, (p+q)}{p (p+4)} = 3 \hspace{10mm} \frac{8 \, (p+q)}{q (q-4)} = 3 \to \frac{8}{3} \, (p+q) = p (p+4) = q (q-4). $$
This gives $p^2 + 4 \, p = q^2 - 4 \, q$ and factors to $(p+q) (p - q + 4) = 0$ which gives $q = -p$ or $q = p + 4$.

The second set of equations follows a similar pattern. First solve for $y$ to obtain $y = 4 \, (p+4)$ and then solve for $x$ which is $x = 4 \, (p+q)$. Then find the relation between $p$ and $q$ from the first line (which is $p (p+4) = q (q-4)$).